# Calculate state-space model from dynamic equations

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

I want to find statespace model of calculated dynamic equations from given equations and eliminations in Mathematica (all the commands should be in one line), but it does not work properly, here is a simple example of my case:

```
StateSpaceModel[{Flatten@Solve[Eliminate[{a == b1 + c *x1''[t], 
b2 == e* (x2[t] - y[t]) + f *(x2'[t] - y'[t]) + d *x2''[t],
g*y''[t] + e*(y[t] - x2[t]) + f*(y'[t] - x2'[t]) + m == 0,
n *z''[t] == m - R, b1 == b2, y[t] == 2* z[t], y'[t] == 2 *z'[t],
y''[t] == 2 *z''[t], x1[t] == x2[t], x1'[t] == x2'[t], x1''[t] == x2''[t]}, 
{b1, b2, y[t], y'[t], y''[t], m, x2[t], x2'[t], x2''[t]}],
{x1''[t], z''[t]}]}, {{x1'[t], 0}, {x1[t], 0}, {z'[t], 0},
{z[t], 0}}, {{a, 0}}, {z'[t], 0}]
```

Calculating dynamic equations from equations and elimination is giving a result for x1''[t] and z''[t] perfectly as desired, but the rest of the code which is to calculate state space model using the defined states to be x1'[t], x1[t], z'[t], z[t] and the output of z'[t] with an input of a is not working.
Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some syntactical errors.

- You need to specify equations and not rules.
- If $a$ is an input variable, it should be specified as $a[t]$.
- Only the operating values of states and inputs need to be specified. The output operating value is determined based on that.
- The temporal variable needs to be specified as well.

  ```
   StateSpaceModel[Equal @@@ 
   Flatten[Solve[Eliminate[{a[t] == b1 + c*x1''[t], 
   b2 == e*(x2[t] - y[t]) + f*(x2'[t] - y'[t]) + d*x2''[t], 
   g*y''[t] + e*(y[t] - x2[t]) + f*(y'[t] - x2'[t]) + m == 0, 
   n*z''[t] == m - R, b1 == b2, y[t] == 2*z[t], y'[t] == 2*z'[t], 
   y''[t] == 2*z''[t], x1[t] == x2[t], x1'[t] == x2'[t], 
   x1''[t] == x2''[t]}, {b1, b2, y[t], y'[t], y''[t], m, x2[t], 
   x2'[t], x2''[t]}], {x1''[t], z''[t]}]], 

   {{x1'[t], 0}, {x1[t], 0}, {z'[t], 0}, {z[t], 0}}, 

   {{a[t], 0}}, 

   z'[t], 

   t]
  ```

> [image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, now it works, but I am wondering does this work for nonlinear dynamic equations as well, if I just change the command to NonlinearStateSpaceModel? @Suba Thomas

Comment: Essentially, yes. It is the same usage. `StateSpaceModel` will throw out all nonlinear terms. `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` will only throw out nonlinearities in the highest order derivatives.

Comment: You can give nonlinear equations to both `StateSpaceModel` and `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` (and also `AffineStateSpaceModel`). The difference is what information each will discard to get the final result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but NonlinearStateSpaceModel command does not give an answer in matrix form (the way that StateSpaceModel command does), so I was wondering is there a way in mixed of nonlinear and linear equations to linearize the nonlinear ones around an applied point and calculate the state space model for both nonlinear and linear differential equations in one line command? @Suba Thomas

Comment: Of course, `NonlinearStateSpaceModel` will not linearize completely, so there are no matrices there. Just use `StateSpaceModel`. It will linearize mixed linear and nonlinear equations. I think you are missing that `StateSpaceModel` is basically a linear model. It will throw away nonlinear terms to do the linearization and get the matrices.

Comment: with StateSpaceModel the matrix becomes a zero matrix! since the equations are related to each other, and with NonlinearStateSpaceModel there is no linearized matrix in the output, and JacobianMatrix does not give a desired result as well. @Suba Thomas

Comment: I have no clue what your issue is. "NonlinearStateSpaceModel there is no linearized matrix in the output". No surprises there. "StateSpaceModel the matrix becomes a zero matrix". So linearization is a bad idea for the application you have in mind. Hard to go any further without a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks. Well I tried to form it in another question to make it clear enough, please find the link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/131205/jacobian-of-nonlinear-dynamic-equations
it is the same linear equations as this case plus one extra nonlinear dynamic equation and two extra states. Hope it is understandable now. @Suba Thomas